# How to add a vertical connector line between material ui icons in list items of a list?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want a vertical line ( connector ) between avtar images in react material UI list item icons.

PFB the sandbox URL.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9z2x527y6r

[Attached image below for the vertical connector line to connect to all images]

Comment: Have you tried with custom CSS classes?

Comment: Have a look at :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yojl4r?file=app/list-sections-example.css

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` element after `ListItem` and apply the following styles and customise it as per your preference.

```js
borderLeft:'1px solid lightgrey',
    height:'3em',
    marginLeft:'2em',
```

[SandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6j3zxv9p8n)